# Visual Studio Workflow Deployment Error

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I'm trying to deploy a 2013 Workflow and I'm getting the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementException: A response was returned that did not come from the Workflow Manager. Status code = 503:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
 Client ActivityId : 4f4d3cd1-  MeetingRequestEmail     0
```

I have no idea what any of this really means... :(

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the Workflow Manager service installed and configured correctly for your farm?